# Phalcon db connection to multiple databases on same host

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection, phalcon

I've recently started using Phalcon PHP Framework, and there is one thing that confuses me a lot.

How to set `$di` to use multiple databases on same host? For example how to make this query work

```
SELECT * FROM
DB1.TABLENAME_1 AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN DB2.TABLENAME_2 AS t2 ON t1.some_id = t2.other_id
```

I've registered connection to DB1 and I've loaded all Models and can easily access data from any Model, but when I'm trying to `JOIN` table from one db with table from second db I'm getting error Model 'TABLENAME_2' could not be loaded which belongs to DB2

here is my `$di`

```
$di->setShared('db', function () use ($config) {
    return new DbAdapter(array(
        'host' => $config->database->host,
        'username' => $config->database->username,
        'password' => $config->database->password,
        'dbname' => $config->database->dbname,
        'options' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"
        )
    ));
});
```

Comment: does the connected user have read permissions on both databases?

Comment: yes it does, I've also created a Model `TABLENAME_2` and Phalcon is trying to map this model with `DB1` instead of `DB2`

Comment: Just add two db connections in DI, and then set connection services in your models: https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/244

Comment: I've tried that and indeed it's working but there is second problem, when I'm using this approach I can add Models via Phalcon devtools

Answer (score 5):

You could add three code-line in your model, for example I have two DB (DB1, DB2), DB1 is primary db and this configs is set in service.php:

### service.php:

```
$di->set('db', function () use ($config) {
    return new DbAdapter(array(
        'host' => "localhost",
        'username' => "root",
        'password' => $config->database->password,
        'dbname' => "DB1",
        'charset' => "utf8"
    ));
});

//declare DB2 as well as:
$di->set('DB2', function () use ($config) {
    return new DbAdapter(array(
        'host' => "localhost",
        'username' => "root",
        'password' => $config->database->password,
        'dbname' => "DB1",
        'charset' => "utf8"
    ));
});
```

And DB2 is the secondary database that you want to use which it involves two table (T1, T2). For any tables of it, you can generate by Phalcon devTools a model.php (T1.php, T2.php). So for using from this tables you should add three code-line to that then define the T1.php class:

### T1.php (This is Your model):

```
class Events extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{

//you can connect to DB2 database
public function initialize()
{
    $this->setConnectionService('DB2');
} 
...
```